# MySQL is reporting CONCAT doesn't exists

Tags: mysql, sql

For some reason there's an error in the following query, it gives "FUNCTION j.CONCAT does not exist" When i remove the concat and just put .price there's no problem so the problem must be somewhere in the concat... The sql retrieves the bought also items from the database.

```
SELECT k.productid_with             AS productid_with, 
   g.product                    AS product_with_product, 
   j.CONCAT('&euro; ', price)   AS productid_with_price, 
   Replace(o.image_path, 
   '/home/user/domains/domain.com/public_html', 
   'http://www.domain.com') AS productid_with_image, 
   Replace(l.image_path, 
   '/home/user/domains/domain.com/public_html', 
   'http://www.domain.com') AS productid_with_bigImage, 
   k.productid, 
   h.product, 
   i.CONCAT('&euro; ', price) AS price, 
   Replace(m.image_path, 
   '/home/user/domains/domain.com/public_html', 
   'http://www.domain.com') AS image, 
   Replace(n.image_path, 
   '/home/user/domains/domain.com/public_html', 
   'http://www.domain.com') AS bigImage 
FROM   xcart_also_bought k 
   JOIN xcart_products_categories c 
     ON c.productid = 8863 
   JOIN xcart_categories d 
     ON c.categoryid = d.categoryid 
        AND d.parentid = 0 
   JOIN xcart_products a 
     ON k.productid_with = a.productid 
        AND a.forsale = 'Y' 
   JOIN xcart_products_categories e 
     ON a.productid = e.productid 
        AND e.categoryid = d.categoryid 
   JOIN xcart_products_lng g 
     ON a.productid = g.productid 
   JOIN xcart_pricing j 
     ON a.productid = j.productid 
   JOIN xcart_thumbnails o 
     ON a.productid = o.productid 
   JOIN xcart_bigthumbnails l 
     ON a.productid = l.productid 
   JOIN xcart_products b 
     ON k.productid = b.productid 
        AND b.forsale = 'Y' 
   JOIN xcart_products_categories f 
     ON b.productid = f.productid 
        AND f.categoryid = d.categoryid 
   JOIN xcart_products_lng h 
     ON b.productid = h.productid 
   JOIN xcart_pricing i 
     ON b.productid = i.productid 
   JOIN xcart_thumbnails m 
     ON b.productid = m.productid 
   JOIN xcart_bigthumbnails n 
     ON b.productid = n.productid 
WHERE  ( k.productid = '8863' 
      OR k.productid_with = '8863' ) 
ORDER  BY bought DESC
```

Comment: Does it report `CONCAT` not exist or `j.CONCAT` not exist?

Comment: @bonCodigo it reports j.CONCAT doesn't exists.

Comment: kind enough to accept it as answer? :) so system will be updated that your question is answered as well.

Comment: @bonCodigo Yeah sure of course. I first couldn't do it since stackoverflow told me to wait. Now it's done :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you use it like this please?

```
CONCAT('&euro; ', j.price)   AS productid_with_price, 

CONCAT('&euro; ', i.price) AS price,
```

And to tell you a secret :D MYSQL doesn't have `j.CONCAT` and `i.CONCAT` ...........
It only has `CONCAT`

To point out explicitly, you are putting table alias on `CONCAT` function where as you should put it on your `fields` :)

Comment: Your query is pretty long mate, so can't blame if your eyes go bonkers at times :D